# Getting 403 while downloading files from a certain folder in an Amazon S3 bucket in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am using one S3 bucket for my Spring boot application.

Here I have created the folder and uploaded files within this in S3 bucket from my Spring boot application with the help of the following `upload` function. Now, while I am listing the files within the folder, I am able to see them. But I cannot download them, getting 403 always.

Code snippet for uploading, listing the objects and downloading thereafter:

```
   //Download is failing
    public File downloadObject(String filePath) {
        File file = null;
        log.info("Downloading object {} from s3 bucket {}", filePath, bucketName);
        try {
          file = File.createTempFile(filePath, "");
          file.deleteOnExit();
          amazonS3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, filePath), file);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
          exception.stackTrace();
        }
        return file;
      }
    
      //Following function is working perfectly fine
      public List<String> listObjects(String pathPrefix) {
        final ListObjectsV2Result listingResponse = amazonS3.listObjectsV2(new ListObjectsV2Request()
            .withPrefix(pathPrefix)
            .withBucketName(bucketName));
        if (Objects.nonNull(listingResponse)) {
          List<String> result = listingResponse.getObjectSummaries().stream().map(
              S3ObjectSummary::getKey).collect(
              Collectors.toList());
          result.remove(pathPrefix);
          return result;
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
      }

    //uploading is also working fine
    public void uploadFile(InputStream inputStream, String filePath) 
    {
    try {
      amazonS3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, filePath, inputStream, null));
    } catch (SdkClientException exception) {
      exception.stackTrace();
    }
  }
```

S3 bucket permission is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAReadWriteAccessToBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456:role/abcd"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see, as per the bucket policy, I have given every permission. Even after this, why the download is failing, not able to figure out. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I am noticing is you are using the old V1 S3 API. Amazon strongly recommends moving to the AWS SDK for Java V2.

**The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.**

The Amazon S3 V2 Java API work nicely in a Spring application. There is a multi service example that shows use of the S3 V2 Java API within a Spring BOOT app. In this use case, we get a byte[] to pass to the Amazon Rekognition  service.

To get a byte[] from an object in an Amazon S3 bucket (which is what i assume you mean when you use the word download), you can use V2 code like this:

```
public byte[] getObjectBytes (String bucketName, String keyName) {

    s3 = getClient();

    try {
        // Create a GetObjectRequest instance
        GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                .builder()
                .key(keyName)
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

        // Get the byte[] from this S3 object
        ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
        byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();
        return data;

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Refer to this end to end example that shows you how to perform this use case in a Spring app. Look at the code in the **S3Service** class.

[Creating an example AWS photo analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

I just ran this app and it works perfectly...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please let me help understand one thing. Is the 403 error coming because of using the old S3 API?

Comment: I find V1 does funny things sometimes and this **may be a bug**.  The AWS Java SDK V2 is a much better API to use. In this V2 example, we use .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create()) to set the creds through use of Environment variables. The creds represent an IAM role that has permissions to invoke S3 operations.

Comment: Yeah @smac2020 I understand. Actually, across the codebase, we are using the v1 AWS SDK. So it seems, I have no other option but to give it a try uplifting the whole code base with the v2 SDK.

Comment: You can find more information about V2 here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html